# Change axis title text color in ggradar

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggradar

I want the tiles around the radar chart (eg `mpg`, `cyl`, `disp`, etc) to be a different color. Is there a way to do this in ggradar? I have tried to do this with the `theme()` argument but doesn't seem to be working. There is an argument within `ggradar` to change font but not color.

```
mtcars %>%
  add_rownames( var = "group" ) %>%
  mutate_each(funs(rescale), -group) %>%
  tail(4) %>% select(1:10) %>% 
  ggradar() + 
  theme(
    axis.title = element_text(color = 'red')
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a look at the docs and the source code of `ggradar()` I'm afraid there  is no option to set the "axis" text color. Actually the axis text is added via multiple `geom_text` layers which is the reason why `theme` options will not work.

One option would be to manipulate the `ggplot` object by first identifying the "text" layers (There are a bunch of (text) layers) and afterwards setting the text colors manually:

```r
library(ggradar)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

p <- mtcars %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var = "group") %>%
  mutate(across(-group, scales::rescale)) %>%
  tail(4) %>% 
  select(1:10) %>% 
  ggradar()

# Text layers
is_text <- sapply(p$layers, function(x) inherits(x$geom, "GeomText") && any(x$data$text %in% names(mtcars)))

p$layers[is_text] <- lapply(p$layers[is_text], function(x) { x$aes_params$colour <- "red"; x})

p
```

[image]

Comment: Ha ha! Within seconds and near identical answers again!

Comment: @AllanCameron Spooky. :D

Answer (score 2):

The circumferential axis labels in ggradar are not "really" axis labels. They are drawn as `geom_text` layers, which is why they don't change when different `theme` elements are applied..

I don't see an option to change them directly, but it's possible to supply the colours to the appropriate layers' aesthetics like this:

```r
p <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column( var = "group" ) %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), scales::rescale)) %>%
  tail(4) %>% 
  select(1:10) %>% 
  ggradar() 

p$layers[[1]]$aes_params <- c(p$layers[[1]]$aes_params, colour = "red")
p$layers[[5]]$aes_params <- c(p$layers[[5]]$aes_params, colour = "red")
p$layers[[6]]$aes_params <- c(p$layers[[6]]$aes_params, colour = "red")

p
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I picked stefan's but could have easily picked this one...same premise.

Comment: I think Stefan's is more generalisable, so it's the right choice @pyll